# Pass array of unknown rank by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11

I am trying to pass by reference an array of unknown number of dimensions (rank). Basically, I'd like to do something like this (which does not compile)

```
template <typename T, int... dims>
void f(T (&arr)[dims]...) // not working
{
    // would like to modify the elements of `arr` here, according to some rule
}

int main()
{
    int arr[2][3][4]; // rank 3
    f(arr);
}
```

Is there any way of achieving this? In particular, is it somehow possible to use a variadic-template approach?

I can do the generic `template<typename T> f(T& arr)`, but in this case how I'd be able to recover the sizes without explicitly passing them? (Even with a variadic template approach I'm not sure how to recover the individual elements in the pack... without some kind of recursive folding).

In particular, I'm looking for a simple way of initializing an unknown-rank array according to some rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just pass an reference to array of type `T`. Then `T` can be another array and so on. No need for complex syntax. So your code will look like this:

```
template <typename T, int sz>
void f(T (&arr)[sz]) // working
{
    std::rank<T[sz]>::value; //evaluates to array rank
}

int main()
{
    int arr[2][3][4]; // rank 3
    f(arr);
}
```

You can then get the array rank by using [`std::rank`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank).

And you can get sub-array sizes by using [`std::remove_extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_extent) and template recursion.

Life [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DshB6qia38y6xPet).

Comment: Thanks, but I think you get the rank with `std::rank<decltype(arr)>::value`, don't you? The issue is that `std::cout << std::rank<decltype(arr)>::value << std::endl;` spits out `0`.

Comment: and `value`, not `value_type`. But even in this case, it seems that `std::rank` believes that a generic type of non-array type is being passed. Trying `std::cout << typeid(arr).name();` gives the proper type, 3-D array, but for some reason `std::rank` doesn't work. Try displaying the rank.

Comment: I think it's because 'decltype(arr)' is a reference to array and not array itself.

Comment: I edited code with the actual type. I think this should be the right way. Also added life working example.